# How to install nodejs on redhat 6

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, redhat

I am trying to install nodejs on my following linux server (actually im not quite sure what version but doesnt look like enterprise):

Linux version 2.6.32-042stab090.5 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat Jun 21 00:15:09 MSK 2014

I ran this:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
```

And had this problem:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 4.x LTS Argon repo...
## Inspecting system...
## You don't appear to be running an Enterprise Linux based system, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support.
```

Answer (score 0):

manage to install now

use nvm

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use NVM, the Node Version Manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Disclaimer: I have tested this on a Centos7 Docker container only (not on RHEL):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
. "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
nvm ls-remote
```

Output (currently):

```
         v4.9.1   (Latest LTS: Argon)
        v6.17.1   (Latest LTS: Boron)
        v8.17.0   (Latest LTS: Carbon)
       v10.22.0   (Latest LTS: Dubnium)
       v12.18.3   (Latest LTS: Erbium)
```

Choose and install one of the latest LTS versions:

```
nvm install v12.18.3
```

Check:

```
node -v
# output: v12.18.3

npm -v
# output: 6.14.6
```

---

*Alternatively: Install the latest LTS Version*

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
. "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
LATEST_LTS=$(nvm ls-remote | grep "Latest LTS" | sed 's/^[^v]*\(v[0-9\.]*\)[^0-9].*$/\1/' | tail -1)
nvm install $LATEST_LTS
```